# Invoke C# library method from Chrome/Firefox (Or extension)

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, device

I would like call a C# library method from Chrome directly from JavaScript or else from a Chrome/Firefox extension.

The goal is to communicate with a C# wrapper that uses a local device, so the idea of coding directly in JavaScript or server-side coding should be ruled out.

Comment: What kind of "device" are you talking about? Technically you can using Blazor WASM which allows running of .Net code within the browser however that code has limited scope and is subject to the browser sandbox.

Comment: It is an NFC reader, so the solution will not fit. The wrapper uses a library that accesses the device driver, it must have access to the system.

Comment: @wOxxOm It seems to fit perfectly with what I'm looking to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `nativeMessaging` API.